# I want to modify helper function to be python2 compatible

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, args

I would like to use this CLI template 
 https://mike.depalatis.net/blog/simplifying-argparse.html
for creating a tool for accessing the EMC Unity REST API.

It appears to be written with python3 in mind.  Particularly the argument helper function.

```
def argument(*name_or_flags, **kwargs):
    return ([*name_or_flags], kwargs)
```

I don't believe I understand exactly how the argument function is supposed to work and thus how I can modify it to work with python2.

e.g. If I had a function create_lun that had a few options, I think I need argument to return a list of arguments defined and thus I would decorate it as so:

```
@subcommand([argument('-o', '--pool', dest='pool', default="pool_1", 
                   type=str, help='Name of Pool of str arg'),
          argument('lun_name', metavar='lun_name', type=str,
                    help='Name of LUN to create in format: ldom-vol#')])
def create_lun(args):
```

and thus cli.py create_lun lun_name would create the lun and -h would show me this syntax.

If that assumption is correct I would need to translate python3's ability to

```
return ([*name_or_flags], kwargs)
```

into a python2.7 equivalent.  Any thoughts on this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
return ([*name_or_flags], kwargs)
```

is the same as

```
return [*name_or_flags], kwargs
```

which is the same as

```
return name_or_flags, kwargs
```

In python 3, the syntax `[*a_list]` expands the elements of a list into a new list literal. It's intended purpose was for inserting an existing list into a new list, not for simply making a copy of a list.

```
In [1]: a = list(range(9))

In [2]: a
Out[2]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

In [3]: [*a]
Out[3]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

In [4]: ['hey', *a, 'there']
Out[4]: ['hey', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'there']
```

To write `[*name_or_flags]` seems like an attempt at obfuscation. Possibly the author had wanted to create a new copy of `name_or_flags`, and in that case a slice would have been enough:

```
def argument(*name_or_flags, **kwargs):
    return name_or_flags[:], kwargs
```

If no copy was needed, then the following will suffice.

```
def argument(*name_or_flags, **kwargs):
    return name_or_flags, kwargs
```

This will work in both Python2 and Python3 and should yield the same results.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  I thought it was trying to do some fancy python3 only type of return. This solved my problem.